# How to convert std::wstring to char const[]

Tags: c++

I have been trying to convert a wstring to a char[] with no success so far. Are these to types totally incompatible or is there a way to convert from one to the other?

I've tried below two approaches with no luck so far.

```
char const testTwo[] = testOne;
char const testTwo[] = testOne.c_str();
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you not just  use `testOne.c_str()` whenever a `const char*` is needed?

Comment: Do you know about `wchar_t const testTwo[] = testOne.c_str();`?

Comment: `std::wstring` often holds UTF16 or UCS2, which work best with 16bit code units. What character encoding did you want the `const char[]` to be, since that's using 8 bit code units?

Comment: I am having problems rendering the character '<' if I simply use my wstring. If I have a hardcoded string with that very same character on a char[], it seems to work well, hence my question :)

Comment: @Galik `c_str` on a `wstring` will return `const wchar_t*`, not `const char*`.

Comment: @user3587624 Rendering where? Maybe you should ask about that particular problem instead.

Comment: @uneven_marl: On a console app

Comment: @user3587624 There is most likely a variant of the function that you want to use that accepts wide strings instead of narrow ones. Again I'd advice you to show your current problem-causing code as a short self-contained example instead of asking about this conversion, which is most likely only a symptom of  a bigger issue.

Comment: What destination encoding do you want the ‘char *’ in? And what OS are you using?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Ask for help with your actual problem (apparently, "rendering the character `<`"), not with your proposed solution that still doesn't work. Show a [mcve].

Comment: `wstring` is a "wide character" string; for all practical purposes unicode. You cannot "convert" it to a `char` without specifying the ***encoding***. If you don't know what ***encoding*** means, then you have to learn what it means first, which is a fairly large topic in of itself, and then figure out which encoding you need to use for converting wide character strings into narrow character strings. Do you need to use ***ISO-8859-1*** encoding? ***ISO-8859-15*** encoding? ***KOI-8R*** encoding? ***UTF-8*** encoding? Or any one of dozens of other encodings in use on the 3rd rock from the sun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must find out how the `std::wstring` is encoded. You should take a look at the documentation of the API  where you get that string.

`std::wstring` is *typically* encoded in system native wide encoding. What the native encoding is, should be specified in the documentation of the system that you are targeting. The native encoding is often be different across different systems, which needs to be taken care of if you intend to target multiple systems. The native wide encoding of Windows is UTF-16, while POSIX typically uses UTF-32.

Next you need to decide what encoding you intend to use for the array of narrow characters. The choice probably depends on what you intend to do with the narrow string. A typically common choice is either UTF-8 or the system native narrow encoding. Just like the wide encoding, the native narrow encoding is system specific. UTF-8 is fairly common on POSIX systems while Windows uses a constant width character set, which depends on the language of the system.

At this point, you should know what encoding you are converting from and to. If you're converting both from wide native encoding to narrow native encoding, then you're in luck. There is a standard function for this: `std::wcsrtombs`.

If either of the encodings is not the native one, then you need to look up the documentation of the respective encodings for what each code unit, code point, grapheme etc. map to. Unicode specification can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/). If you're converting into non-unicode, then you need to decide what to do with characters that don't have a corresponding code point in the target encoding.

As always, it is a good idea to save time by using existing software. You can skip learning different encodings and their conversions by using an existing library such as [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

P.S. You probably have no way of knowing the length of the resulting narrow string at compile time, so you probably need to allocate the array dynamically. This also means that the array cannot be const. I recommend using `std::string` for this purpose